# How to match this string with regex

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, regex

So I have this string: (a url)

```
example.html/#playYouTubeVideo=id[lBs8jPDPveg]&width[160]&height[90]
```

I want to match id, width and height. And the value in [ ]

I came up with this:

```
[=|&](\w+)(?!\[)(.+?)(?=\])
```

But the match for group #1: **i**, **widt** and **heigh**
And the match for group #2: **d[lBs8jPDPveg**, **h[160** and **t[90**

So the error is that the last letter in the name and [ is in group #2
Anyone got an idea how to fix it?

Comment: Which language are you really using, PHP or Javascript?

Comment: `(?!\[)` is a look-behind pattern that actually matches the empty string. It just makes some statement about your current position. So the next `(.+?)` includes the `[` since it is not consumed by the look-behind pattern.

Comment: did you try `[=|&](\w+)\[([^]]+)\]` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you do:

```
[=&|](\w+)\[([^\]]+)\]
```

Group 1 will have id, width, height, group 2 will have what's in the `[]`.

(Do you actually want the `|` in that preceding bit?)